# Flutter Android folder

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

I have just taken over a project the previous developer has created .Android folder instead of the normal Android folder (actually done for both iOS and Android) can somebody explain why and what the benefit is - I need to update the SDK level and make some other updates. Thanks in Advance

have tried moving back but the system now seems to be continually looking for the .android

Comment: Where do you see that Android folder?

Comment: The only reason I can think of is to make the folder invisible since this is a pattern used on Linux, system folders on MacOs also start with a .

Comment: yeah - I just dont understand why they would want the andorid folder hidden - the folder is in the default location, has all the standard info - files etc